# Chosen: Show options that starts with the letter typed

Tags: jquery, jquery-chosen

Chosen library has the option `search_contains` which if set to `true`, Search in middle of the word and if set to `false`, Search from start of the word.

But it does not have an option like `Search from start of the select option`.

Is there any way I can achieve this? or is there any other library which supports this options.

I also checked select2 jquery plugin but it also does not have such option.

Comment: extend chosen library

Comment: @Satpal How? can you tell me a clue where to start?